# Codeigniter -fetching data sitewide with codeigniter hooks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get scroll news in any page of the website from database without having to pass the variable in every controller of the site. So I decided to use hooks instead of passing scroll variable in every controller.

I did create a class like this

```
class Scroll
{

 function getScroller()
 {

  $data = array();

  $CI =& get_instance();

  $CI->db->where('a_status','active');
  $CI->db->limit(4);
  $CI->db->order_by('id','desc');

  $Q = $CI->db->get('news');
  if($Q->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($Q->result_array() as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $Q->free_result();
  return $data;
 }



}
```

What I get now is

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Call to a member function get() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this ? Thanks I want to get scrollernews in any controller's view automatically without having to pass in each controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining that on a view level, there is no need for that.

You can define db requests directly in a view.

Other approach would be to have separated controller which with separate view and load it in the page through iframe. It's often used for "web widgets" that can be later on loaded in to another pages.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the core class of CI Controller will should cause you less troubles.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

*application/core/MY_Controller.php*

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //By do this, all controllers who use this class as parent controller
        //will have $news in their views
        $this->load->vars(array( 
             'news' =>  array()
        ));
    }   
}
```

*application/controller/welcome.php*

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {       
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

application/views/welcome_message.php

```
var_dump($news);
```

Answer (score 0):

use separated library or helper and call that method on controller's constructs like :

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller(){

    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    //load your library
    //call your library method
    }
    }
```